# How bad is using jQuery extend for namespacing?

Tags: jquery, namespaces

From what I can tell, in a current project, the devs have used jQuery extend to handle the namespacing. How bad is this?

```
var my = $.extend({}, {
    itemone: 0
}

$.extend(my, {
    init: function() {}
}

$(function() {
    my.init();
})();
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the above code. In the initial `var my` declaration, you use extend to push an object into an empty object, yet you're defining the object you want to push into it...why bother? `var my = { itemone: 0}`..if you want to then manipulate the properties of one object with propreties of another object, that's what extend is for, otherwise, i can't see a reason to bother with this. `var my = {itemone:0}` ... later on ... `my.init = function(){}`....extend isn't needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simple example code you posted you don't really need to use `$.extend`, but in general, I wouldn't say using jquery `$.extend` to help with namespacing is 'bad'.  See [this post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) about javascript namespacing patterns.

According to the author, using 'extend' or 'deep object extension' is considered an advanced namespace extension technique.  Using jQuery's `$.extend` makes the technique fairly easy, though probably adds a certain amount of overhead.

I've never used it in that way, but in big app with some complicated/deep namespacing, using `$.extend` might be helpful.  I wouldn't load jquery library just to use its extend method though.